# Django way for dynamic forms with dependencies?

Tags: django, forms, if-statement, dependencies, required

I'm looking for a django way to handle some complex forms with a lot of business logic. The issue is many of my forms have dependencies in them.
Some examples:
1. two "select" (choice) fields that are dependent on each other. For example consider two dropdowns one for Country and one for  City.
2. A "required-if" rule, i.e set field required if something else in the form was selected. Say if the user select "Other" option in a select field, he need to add an explanation in a textarea.
3. Some way to handle date/datetime fields, i.e rules like max/min date?

What I'm doing now is implementing all of these in the form `clean()`, `__init__()`, and write some (tedious) client-side JS.

I wonder if there is a better approach? like defining these rules in a something similar to django `Meta` classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to necro this thread, because I don't see a good answer yet. If you are trying to validate a field and you want that field's validation to depend on another field in that same form, use the clean(self) method.

**Here's an example**: Say you have two fields, a "main_image" and "image_2". You want to make sure that if a user uploads a second image, that they also uploaded a main image as well. If they don't upload an image, the default image will be called 'default_ad.jpg'.

**In forms.py:**

```
class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Ad

    fields = [
        'title',
        'main_image',
        'image_2',
        'item_or_model_names',
        'category',
        'buying_or_selling',
        'condition',
        'asking_price',
        'location',
    ]

  def clean(self):
  # "Call the cleaned form"
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        main_image = cleaned_data.get("main_image")
        image_2 = cleaned_data.get("image_2")

        if "default_ad" not in image_2:
            # Check to see if image_2's name contains "default_ad"
            if "default_ad" in main_image:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Oops, you didn't upload a main image."
                )
```

If you want more info, read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1.This task is souly related the the html building of the form, not involving django/jinga.
2.Here, you go to dynamic forms. the best and most used way nowdays to do this, is through JS.
3.try building a DB with a "time" type field and then through "admin" watch how they handle it. all of special fields useage is covered here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/

Comment: for (1), I wouldn't say that. If you have dependent dropdowns, you still need to validate (server-side) that they match. So it is some type of "constraint". And yeah, it is about html rendering too (JS), as I need to update the form based on the select value.

Comment: And obviously some part of the issues here are JS/client-related. Currently I'm looking at libraries like angular, cause jQuery only seems to not fit enough when dealing with a lot of logic, and I end up with tons of callbacks and event handlers..

Comment: Another problem came to mind - when you are doing JS validation on client side, tedious at it sometimes is.. I hard-code my field names. because it's hard to use the "django" names.